# Incompatible libraries in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

i want to use gcm in my app, but while adding dependancies in gradle file i got error of incompatible libraries. 
my app level gradle file have dependancies as follows ..

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.appvirality:AppviralityUI:1.1.18+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

and i have added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'`
in my project level gradle.

my google play services is updated to latest version but still it shows error like..
All libraries must use the exact same version specifications. 
After checking i got know that it conflicts `compile 'com.appvirality:AppviralityUI:1.1.18+'` library.

Thanks

Comment: #Newbiee : Check my answer https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know how.. but, Got it wroking just by changing compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to change this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

You can set your **classpath** as `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

Comment: i have already added both the lines you said.. but its not working i have followed the link  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @Newbiee `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` set this .

Comment: on adding it.. it shows error like "Can not add extension with name android, as it is already registered"   as apply plugin: 'com.android.application' is already there

Comment: @Newbiee `apply plugin: 'android'`

Comment: can you please check the edit?.. i have added the conflicting library

Comment: @Newbiee remove `+` sign .use `com.appvirality:AppviralityUI:1.1.18'` .Then Clean-Rebuild.Hope it will helps you